# How can I make this method more efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've written a helper methods to convert the city in street addresses to its corresponding FIPS Place code:

```
def place_fips
    place_fips = 'PLACE:' + Place.where(statename: @address.state, placeshort: @address.city ).first.placefp
end
```

I now want to use "place_fips" in several other methods, which fetch demographic data for the city:

```
def city_pop_tot
    str = @census.where({ fields: 'P0030001', level: place_fips })[0]["P0030001"].to_i
end
```

I currently have about seven of these `city_pop_foo` methods (one for each race category—eg, `city_pop_white`, `city_pop_black`, `city_pop_asian`, etc.)

This all *works* fine, but the response time is way too long because it runs the `place_fips` query each time it hits one of the `city_pop_foo` methods. Is there a way to define `place_fips` once, and use it in the subsequent methods without fetching it from the database each time?

Also, I suspect there's a way to—instead of having several `def city_pop_foo` methods—DRY this code and just define `def city_pop` once, then pass in arguments that will change the `P00####` in the `@census.where` query (so I could write something like `<%= city_pop(white) %>`, `<%= city_pop(black) %>`, `<%= city_pop(asian) %>`, etc. in my views). Am I on the right track here? What might something like this look like?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code that needs refactoring, which is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this is memoization. Consider the following example:

```
class Greeter
  def greet
    puts greeting
  end

  def greeting
    compute_greeting
  end

  private

  def compute_greeting
    sleep 3 # heavy lifting
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end

greeter = Greeter.new
greeter.greet          # takes ~3 seconds
greeter.greet          # takes ~3 seconds as well
greeter.greet          # takes ~3 seconds as well
```

Now to solve this, you can use an instance variable named like the method and conditional assignment with `||=` which will only set the variable if it's `nil`, and return the saved version otherwise:

```
class Greeter
  def greet
    puts greeting
  end

  def greeting
    @greeting ||= compute_greeting
  end

  private

  def compute_greeting
    sleep 3 # heavy lifting
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end

greeter = Greeter.new
greeter.greet          # takes ~3 seconds
greeter.greet          # runs instantly
greeter.greet          # runs instantly
```

Of course, if the cached content depends on the state of the object in any way, you need to do the housekeeping when the state changes. The following code is broken, for example:

```
class PersonalGreeter
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet
    puts greeting
  end

  def greeting
    @greeting ||= compute_greeting
  end

  private

  def compute_greeting
    sleep 3 # heavy lifting
    "Hello, #{name}!"
  end
end

greeter = PersonalGreeter.new('Sergio Hernandez')
greeter.greet # Hello, Sergio Hernandez!
greeter.name = 'Zaphod Beeblebrox'
greeter.greet # Hello, Sergio Hernandez!
```

So you need to clear the cached/memoized greeting whenever the name changes:

```
class PersonalGreeter
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name=(new_name)
    @greeting = nil
    @name = new_name
  end

  def greet
    puts greeting
  end

  def greeting
    @greeting ||= compute_greeting
  end

  private

  def compute_greeting
    sleep 3 # heavy lifting
    "Hello, #{name}!"
  end
end

greeter = PersonalGreeter.new('Sergio Hernandez')
greeter.greet # Hello, Sergio Hernandez!
greeter.name = 'Zaphod Beeblebrox'
greeter.greet # Hello, Zaphod Beeblebrox!
```

This is only a simple example and already got fairly complex. As you can imagine, this quickly gets out of hand with larger classes, so make sure you use memoization sparingly, only in the places where there's a real benefit to it.